# How do you configure StyleCop to run for a specific build configuration?

Tags: stylecop, csproj

I've added the following imports statement to the csproj file:

```
<Import Project="..\..\..\packages\StyleCop 4.7\StyleCop.targets" />
```

This work fine, however I only want the style cop analysis to run on Debug builds and not on Release builds.  My Google Fu is failing me today, although I have found that you can create a console command line wrapper for `StyleCopConsole` and run it manually (http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Running%20StyleCop%20from%20Your%20Code), I'd rather just edit the project files if that's possible so that it runs automatically on Debug builds.

Any idea if this is possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could  conditionally import the targets

```
<Import Project="..\..\..\packages\StyleCop 4.7\StyleCop.targets" Condition="$(Configuration)=='Debug'"/>
```

Comment: Mmmm ... this is not working in VS2008 and StyleCop 4.3 ... any ideas?

Comment: does the msbuild targets file exist?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to run StyleCop every time you compile in Debug version?  StyleCop is a pig (but a good pig) and this is a huge waste of the CPU's time and your time.  Run StyleCop when you're ready to release.

Comment: Agreed, just answering the question put. I'd put it in an analysis nightly build myself certainly not interfering with devs local or any ci build. Although as a contractor ive seen dumber.